# Проблема ajax загрузки файла

Tags: javascript

```html
<form name='upload' action='/index.php?act=upload&a=photo' method='post'
    enctype='multipart/form-data' target='rframe'>

    <div style='display: none'>
        <input type='file' id='photo' name='photo'
            onchange='document.getElementById("load").click()'
            multiple='true' style='visibility: hidden; position: absolute;'>
        <input type='submit' name='load' id='load'>
    </div>
</form>

<iframe name='rframe' id='rframe' width='300' height='50'
    class='iframe_music' hidden></iframe>
```

<sub>Обработчик формы, который перестал работать</sub>

```
document.forms.upload.onsubmit = function() {
    var input = this.elements.photo;
    var file = input.files[0];
    if(file) {
        upload_file(file, true);
    }
    return false;
}
```

При изменении `<input type='file'>` срабатывает `onchange`, где происходит нажатие на кнопку `<input type='submit'>`. Нажатие происходит, но скрипт перестал ловить событие `onsubmit`. Я даже прописывал `alert()` - ничего. До этого скрипт работал нормально.

Суть скрипта в том, что он передает файл функции, которая загружает его асинхронно, а когда данный скрипт перестал работать, то теперь происходит загрузка файла по дедовскому способу, обновляя страницу. В чем может быть проблема данного скрипта?

На всякий случай сама функция `upload_file`

```
function upload_file(file, bool = false) {
    var xhr = xml.http();
    var form = new FormData();
    var btn = ge('btn_upload');
    if(btn != null) btn.style.display = 'none';

    var pr = ge('progress');
    var percent = ge("percent");
    var percent_ = ge("percent_");
    if(pr != null) pr.style.display = "block";

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
        var total = event.total;
        var load  = event.loaded;
        var progress = ge('progress_line');
        var prof  = load / total * 100;

        progress.style.width = Math.floor(prof) + '%';
        percent.innerHTML = Math.floor(prof) + '%';
        percent_.innerHTML = Math.floor(prof) + '%';

        if(Math.floor(prof) == 100) {
            if(!bool) reg_info.stepNext(3);
        } else {
            photo.closeBox();
        }
    }
}

xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        console.log('success');
    } else {
        console.log('error ' + this.status);
    }
}

form.append('photo', file);
    xhr.open('POST', '/index.php?act=upload&a=photo', true);
    xhr.send(form);
}
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоли какие?

Comment: В том то и дело, что их нет. На одной странице все работает, а на другой нет. Полностью уже скопировал и вставил, вдруг ошибся, когда писал, но нет, не хочет работать и все.

Comment: добавь обработчик `onchange`

Comment: @Grundy, так там же есть, в нем происходит нажатие на кнопку: `onchange='document.getElementById("load").click()'` .

Answer (score 2):

Для чего вам `iframe`, если вы используете `XMLHttpRequest2`?

```
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" multiple="true">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('photo');

    //Если 2 раза выбрать один и тот же файл - событие не сработает, после каждого выбора файла клонируем и заменяем элемент на странице
    function replaceSelect() {
        var clone = fileSelect.cloneNode();
        clone.addEventListener('change',function (e){
            replaceSelect();
            console.log(this.files);
            //Ваш код
        });

        fileSelect.parentNode.replaceChild(clone);

        fileSelect = clone;
    }

    replaceSelect();
</script>
```

С первого взгляда функция загрузки в порядке)

Comment: В `iframe` отправляется форма. Да, функция загрузки в порядке. Не работает вот этот код `document.forms.upload.onsubmit = function() {...}`, а почему, не знаю. До него просто не доходит событие